# Charging one thing with static electricity by using battery

Tags: electrostatics

How can I make one thing to get statically charged by using batteries but not friction ?  For example charge a rod so it can attract shredding ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the charge on an object is given by:

$$ Q = V C $$

where $C$ is the capacitance of the object and $V$ is the voltage. So the charge is proportional to the voltage and at battery voltages the charge $Q$ is going to be tiny - you typically need thousands of volts to get a significant charge.

What you could do is use your battery to power an [induction coil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_coil) and use this to generate the high voltages required.

Comment: I would use an ignition coil http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignition_coil. Instead of the spark plug connect the staff to be loaded and the ground where the shredding lies around.

Comment: But this would only work for a conductive object (as opposed to something like a PVC rod), correct? Or is there some other way to deposit charge on an insulator, but without friction (like shooting electrons at it)?